# How does Android/BroadcastReceiver determine if Wifi P2P is enabled?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, wifip2p

I've been following Google's WIFIDirect demo pretty much to the letter, but upon clicking the acitionBar button responsible for calling discoverPeers(), I get the message telling me "WifiDirect is not enabled". This is tied to a boolean that's checked by the broadcastReceiver upon the onReceive snippet below:

```
if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){

    //Update UI to show WifiP2p status
    int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,-1);

    if(state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED){
        //Wifi Direct Enabled
        //we keep the WifiP2pEnabled boolean within the activity,
        //So it wont change, and can be followed
        activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
    }else{
        activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);
        activity.resetData();
    }
    Log.d(WIFIDirectActivity.TAG,"P2P state changed" +state);
```

So naturally it's not reading my WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED on my LG G3, but it other WifiDirect apps on the market seem to work? I've manually set the boolean to true, in which case it works and discovers/connects to peers without issue.

Could it actually be my android version (4.4.2) that's the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Did you setup a receiver with the correct intentfilter and action?

Comment: You struck gold. I left one out in the receiver. My thanks, and a happy new year to you!

Comment: That is good to hear. I forgotten this quite a lot as well when I started working with receivers. Have a good new year also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on an educated guess and something I have forgotten a million times as well. The problem here is an incomplete addition to the manifest.

```
<application
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <receiver android:name="MyReceiver">

      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
             <!-- BOOT_COMPLETED can be any action you might want to receive -->
         </action>
      </intent-filter>

   </receiver>
</application>
```

Above you see an example of how this should look like.